# Symfony2 form isclicked doesn't work

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to submit a form with 2 buttons but the method isclicked doesn't work...

```
$user = $repository->find($id);
$formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($user);
$form = $formBuilder->add('username', 'text',array(
                'label' => "Pseudo :"))
            ->add('email', 'text', array(
            'label' => "E-mail address :"))
            ->add('save', 'submit',array(
            'label' => 'Save',
            'attr' => array( 'class' => 'btn btn-primary')))
            ->add('reset', 'submit',array(
            'label' => 'Reset pwd',
            'attr' => array( 'class' => 'btn btn-primary')))
            ->getForm();
$request = $this->get('request');
if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
    $value = $form->get('save')->isClicked()  ?'save' :'reset';
    echo $value;
```

Below my twig:

```
<section>
  {{ form_start(form) }}
   {{form_errors(form) }}
    <div class='form_group'>
      {{form_row(form.username)}}
      {{form_row(form.email)}}
      <br>
      <div class='testbutton'>
      {{form_row(form.save)}}
      {{form_row(form.reset)}}
    </div>
  {{ form_end(form) }}
  </div>
</section>
```

But it doesn't matter which button I pressed this code will always display "reset"...

What is wrong? :/

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I noticed that you didn't `handleRequest`:

```
$request = $this->get('request');
if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
    $form->handleRequest($request); // <== THIS

    $value = $form->get('save')->isClicked()  ?'save' :'reset';
    echo $value;
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hello, it works! You found the mistake! In documentation there is nothing about that and the method looks to belong to the retuned object from formBuilder

Comment: Yes, I looked over official docs and noticed the same thing. Glad I could help ;)

Comment: ... also, please accept this answer so the other SO users would know if it could help them. ;)